# изменение значения указателя

Tags: c, указатели

и снова привет! продолжаю изучение указателей, и на сей раз задался вопросом: что если представить ситуацию, где указатель ссылается на переменную, а после над этим же указателем провести операцию инкремента или декремента, то куда и на что он будет указывать?
решил сам написать код, значения весьма странные, но думаю это тоже связано с битовым представлением числа, как мне подсказали в прошлый раз

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main(void) {
    int a = 1;
    float b = 2;
    double c = 3;
    int* p1 = &a;
    float* p2 = &b;
    double* p3 = &c;
    p1 = (int*)p2;
    p3 = (double*)p2;
    p1++;
    p3--;
    printf("p1=%p\tp2=%p\tp3=%p\n", p1, p2, p3);
    printf("*p1=%d\t\t*p2=%f\t*p3=%lf\n",
        *p1, *p2, *p3);
    p1 -= 4;
    p3 = (double*)&a - 1;
    printf("p1=%p\tp2=%p\tp3=%p\n", p1, p2, p3);
    printf("*p1=%d\t*p2=%f\t*p3=%lf\n",
        *p1, *p2, *p3);
   return 0;
}
```

Буду также рад и источникам с информацией о вопросе!

Comment: `значения весьма странные`  В чём странность?

Comment: @wololo на что указывают указатели? что это за значения? почему они такие? я пока не разбираюсь полностью в теме указателей, поэтому для меня такие значения будут странными

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Привет) Инкремент и декремент указателя, соответственно, увеличивает и уменьшает содержащийся в нём адрес на величину, равную размеру типа данных, на которые он ссылается. Об этом написано в любом учебнике по C/C++, так что не совсем понятно, в чём возник вопрос. Но всё равно проясню.

Возможны следующие варианты.

1. Указатель ссылается на элемент массива. Тогда после инкремента он будет ссылаться на следующий элемент массива. Если он перед этим ссылался на последний элемент, то после инкремента он станет указывать за пределы массива - в этом случае обращение к содержимому по этому указателю вызовет неопределённое поведение (Undefined Behavior, UB). Аналогично для декремента - будет указывать на предыдущий элемент. Если до декремента указатель ссылался на первый элемент, то после он опять таки вывалится за пределы массива, только уже с другой стороны - и снова будет UB при обращении по такому указателю.
2. Указатель ссылается на одиночную переменную или объект. В этом случае инкремент, либо декремент приведёт к тому, что этот указатель будет ссылаться за пределы переменной или объекта. И обращение по нему вызовет UB.
3. Указатель ссылается на неизвестно что (например, он не был проинициализирован и содержит мусор). Чтение либо запись данных через этот указатель, как нетрудно догадаться, вызовет UB.

А теперь, исходя из выше написанного, ответы на ваши вопросы:

- Вопрос: на что указывают указатели? Ответ: на что-то такое, что вы не контролируете. Если указатель указывал на переменную `a`, а вы сделали ему инкремент, то он будет указывать на что-то за `a`. По чистой случайности это могут оказаться данные переменной `b`. А может это будут байты выравнивания между переменной `a` и какой-нибудь другой переменной (вовсе не обязательно, что это будет `b`). А может за пределами переменной `a` вообще ничего не быть - пустая страница виртуальной памяти без физического отображения, в этом случае при попытке прочитать что-нибудь оттуда ваша программа просто закрэшится с ошибкой "Access violation..." или что-то в этом роде. В этом вся суть неопределённого поведения.
- Вопрос: что это за значения? Ответ: неопределённые (см. ответ выше).
- Вопрос: почему они такие? Ответ: потому что UB. Неопределённое поведение, которого при написании программ, следует избегать любой ценой.

Comment: очень информативный ответ, браво! но хочется задать еще немного: получается объяснить такие значения, если указатель указывает на «пустоту» никак нельзя? о каком UB идет речь(что это?)? указатель указывает только на одну ячейку памяти или сразу на все, на которых записана переменная? -Если да, то при операции инкремента или декремента на какое количество ячеек памяти он будет указывать?

Comment: @ualdrm Указатель в качестве своего значения содержит адрес *первого байта объекта*, на который он указывает. А о том, сколько байт занимает сам объект (и какую величину, соответственно, надо прибавить или вычесть при инкременте/декременте), компилятору говорит тип объекта. По-моему вы уже задавали подобный вопрос.

Comment: @ualdrm UB - это неопределённое поведение, т.е. это когда программа ведёт себя непредсказуемо. И значения, которые вы хотите объяснить, соответственно, - также непредсказуемы. Нет, разумеется вы можете дизассемблировать *данный конкретный вариант сборки* программы, изучить, как именно компилятор распределил память, и точно узнать, почему хотя бы некоторые значения получились в этот раз такими. Однако поменяйте местами переменные, слегка измените код,, скомпилируйте программу с другими опциями, или даже на другом компиляторе - и эти значения изменятся. По-этому просто нет смысла их объяснять.